# Check for video metadata stream in net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, video-streaming

I have a WebAPI that need to download a video from http url. Before to save that video i need to check if the data download is a VideoStream, and the property of that video (size, resolution, duration).

What's the best way or library that can I use in C# for do that check?

The response that i expect is mp4 file video
RESPONSE SCHEMA: application/octet-stream

Comment: It depends on which particular http endpoint you are downloading from and what format they send the data as, please share more information on the kind of endpoint you are obtaining the video from

Comment: Thanks, the response that i expect is mp4 file video  RESPONSE SCHEMA: application/octet-stream